# How to detect a self referencing list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been trying to find a self-referencing loop in a list. I have referenced the list like this:

```
a = [1, 2, None] 
a[2] = a
```

What is the right way to detect this loop in python?

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure if there's a "right" way, but the `is` operator is your friend. To check if the list contains itself:

```
any(x is a for x in a)
```

To find the index of the list:

```
next(i for i, x in enumerate(a) if x is a)
```

This version is like `a.index` in that it raises an error if the list is not found in itself. To simulate `a.find` instead, add a default value to `next`:

```
next(..., -1)
```

You can't use `a.find` or `a.index` directly because those will search by equality, which will be infinitely recursive on a positive match in this case.

Checking for identity should be relatively foolproof in this case.